# iOS7 iPhone: how to make Siri-initiated calls, SMS text msgs come from Google Voice caller ID?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios, google-voice, caller-id

When I ask Siri (iOS 7.0.4 on my iPhone 5S) to call or text someone, I want said call or text to come from my Google Voice caller ID.  Any way to do this now that jailbreak apps GVIntegrated & Phone GV Extension appear to no longer be available (at least for my phone, details below)?

All other Google Voice functionality seems to be handled just fine via the Google Voice "standard" app from Google.

I've jailbroken said phone searching for a way, with no success.  GVIntegrated indeed reads "not certified on this device" and Phone GV Extension doesn't even come up in the search list on Cydia.  Phone GV Extension worked well on my iPhone 4S running 5.x (and maybe 6.x), although my iPhone seemed to be a bit less stable (reboot/crashes) in jailbroken mode.

Comment: After more than a month, no suggestions.  Apparently nothing exists for iOS7... (?)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in 2014 and neither is it possible in fall of 2019.

Unless there’s an API or other way to script this, you might need to use a mac or other python enabled tool to automate this.

- [How can I initiate a Google Voice phone call from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40274/how-can-i-initiate-a-google-voice-phone-call-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score -2):

I just found Call on GV Pro (jailbreak needed) that works on iOS 7.1.2